# In excel how to determine at which row a month begins and at which row it ends?

Tags: excel

In Excel I have a sheet similar to bank statement, with a column for transaction date , then other columns for amount and other details. The sheet is sorted by date. The main requirement is I need a function that determines at which row the month begins and ends. The problem is that business needs to change sometimes goes back few months and add few rows, or delete some, hence month position for the following months changes constantly. The question is how in excel can I determine at which row a month begins and at which row it ends ?

Comment: Can a date appear more than once in the date column ??

Answer (score 0):

Say our data like like:

[image]

and we want the start and end rows for October 2020.

First enter the following User Defined Functions in a standard module:

```
Public Function FirstRow(rng As Range, mnth As Long, yr As Long) As Long
    Dim r As Range, v As Date
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If Month(v) = mnth And Year(v) = yr Then
            FirstRow = r.Row
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
    FirstRow = 0
End Function


Public Function LastRow(rng As Range, mnth As Long, yr As Long) As Long
    Dim r As Range, v As Date, boo As Boolean, i As Long, kol As Long
    
    boo = False
    
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If Month(v) = mnth And Year(v) = yr Then
            boo = True
        End If
        If boo Then
            If Month(v) <> mnth Or Year(v) <> yr Then
                LastRow = r.Row - 1
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    LastRow = 0
End Function
```

To use the UDFs we, for example, put 10 in **D1** and 2020 in **E1** and then use:

```
=FirstRow(A1:A26,D1,E1)
=LastRow(A1:A26,D1,E1)
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Answer (score 0):

What about the simple `Month()` Excel function? You can create a helper column, containing the month of the mentioned date, and on that column, put an autofilter. You can filter on any month you like and you can see the beginning and ending row on screen. You don't need any programming for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with worksheet formulas.

- Month StartDate Row:

  ```
  =AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((MONTH(Dates)=D2)*(YEAR(Dates)=E2))*ROW(Dates),1)
  ```
- Month EndDate Row

  ```
   =AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((MONTH(Dates)=D2)*(YEAR(Dates)=E2))*ROW(Dates),1)
  ```

In the screenshot, the month start is highlighted in Green; and the month End in Red.

[image]

*Note:  If there are duplicate start or end dates, the detected row will be the first start date, or the last end date. If that is not what you want, please be clarify.*

Comment: This AGGREGATE function worked perfectly, Thank you Ron